# mongoexport JSON assertion: 10340 Failure parsing JSON string

Tags: json, mongodb, command-line, export

I'm trying to export CSV file list from mongoDB and save the output file to my directory, which is /home/asaj/. The output file should have the following columns: name, file_name, d_start and d_end.
The query should filter data with status equal to "FU" or "FD", and d_end > Dec. 10, 2012.

In mongoDB, the query is working properly. The query below is limited to 1 data output. See query below:

```
> db.Samples.find({ $or : [ { status : 'FU' }, { status : 'FD'} ], d_end : { $gte : ISODate("2012-12-10T00:00:00.000Z") } }, {_id: 0, name: 1, file_name: 1, d_start: 1, d_end: 1}).limit(1).toArray();
[
    {
            "name" : "sample"
            "file_name" : "sample.jpg",
            "d_end" : ISODate("2012-12-10T05:1:57.879Z"),
            "d_start" : ISODate("2012-12-10T02:31:34.560Z"),
    }

]
>
```

In CLI, mongoexport command looks like this:

```
mongoexport -d maindb -c Samples -f "name, file_name, d_start, d_end" -q "{'\$or' : [ { 'status' : 'FU' }, { 'status' : 'FD'} ] , 'd_end' : { '\$gte' : ISODate("2012-12-10T00:00:00.000Z") } }" --csv -o "/home/asaj/currentlist.csv"
```

But i always ended up with this error:

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Wed Dec 19 16:58:17 Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: , 'd_end
0x5858b2 0x528cb4 0x52902e 0xa9a631 0xa93e4d 0xa97de2 0x31b441ecdd 0x4fd289
mongoexport(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x112) [0x5858b2]
mongoexport(_ZN5mongo8fromjsonEPKcPi+0x444) [0x528cb4]
mongoexport(_ZN5mongo8fromjsonERKSs+0xe) [0x52902e]
mongoexport(_ZN6Export3runEv+0x7b1) [0xa9a631]
mongoexport(_ZN5mongo4Tool4mainEiPPc+0x169d) [0xa93e4d]
mongoexport(main+0x32) [0xa97de2]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x31b441ecdd]
mongoexport(__gxx_personality_v0+0x3c9) [0x4fd289]
assertion: 10340 Failure parsing JSON string near: , 'd_end
```

I'm having error in "**, 'd_end'** " in mongoexport CLI. I'm not so sure if it is a JSON syntax error because query works on MongoDB.
Please help.

Comment: try flipping around the quotes.  Put single quotes outside the entire query and use double quotes inside where you need quoted strings.

Answer (score 2):

After asking someone knows MongoDB better than me, we found out that the problem is the

```
ISODate("2012-12-10T00:00:00.000Z")
```

We found the answer on this question: [mongoexport JSON parsing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098191/mongoexport-json-parsing-error)

To resolve this error, first, we convert it to **strtotime**:

```
php > echo strtotime("12/10/2012");
1355126400
```

Next, **multiple strtotime result by 1000**. This date will looks like this:

```
1355126400000
```

Lastly, change **ISODate("2012-12-10T00:00:00.000Z")** to **new Date(1355126400000)** in the mongoexport command.

Now, the CLI mongoexport looks like this and it works:

```
mongoexport -d maindb -c Samples -f "id,file_name,d_start,d_end" -q "{'\$or' : [ { 'status' : 'FU' }, { 'status' : 'FD'} ] , 'd_end' : { '\$gte' : new  Date(1355126400000) } }" --csv -o "/home/asaj/listupdate.csv"
```

**Note:** remove space between each field names in -f or --fields option.

Answer (score 2):

I know it has little to do with this question, but the title of this post brought it up in Google so since I was getting the exact same error I'll add an answer. Hopefully it helps someone.

My issue was adding a MongoId query for _id to a mongoexport console command on Windows. Here's the error:

```
Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: _id
```

The problem ended up being that I needed to wrap the JSON query in double quotes, *and* the ObjectId had to be in double quotes (not single!), so I had to escape those quotes. Here's the final query that worked, for future reference:

```
 mongoexport -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -d DATABASE -c COLLECTION 
   --query "{_id : ObjectId(\"5148894d98981be01e000011\")}"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, though I didn't need double quotes around the entire query. This worked for me: -q '{_id : ObjectId("5148894d98981be01e000011")}'

So the single quotes in ObjectIds seem to be key.