# why can mongoexport not parse this JSON when mongo can?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoexport

this is the query:

```
mongoexport --host our.dbhost.com --port 27017 --username peter -p clark --collection sent_mails --db dbname --query '{trigger_id:ObjectId( "50c62e97b9fe6a000200000c"), updated_at: {$lt : ISODate("2013-02-28"), $gte : ISODate("2013-02-01") }}'
```

when I run this command I get:

```
assertion: 10340 Failure parsing JSON string near: , updated_
```

any ideas? (i want all records that match the trigger_id that were updated in February.)

Answer (score 1):

as explained in this issue: [Mongoexport using $gt and $lt constraints on a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758605), you have to use Unix time stamps for date queries in mongoexport

The time stamps have to be in milliseconds

Invoking this in the bash shell would look like this:

```
let "date_from=`date --utc --date "2013-02-01" +%s` * 1000"
let "date_to=`date --utc --date "2013-03-01" +%s` * 1000"
mongoexport -d test -c xx --query "{updated_at:{\$gte:new Date($date_from),\$lt:new Date($date_to)}}"> xx.json
> connected to: 127.0.0.1
> exported 1 records
```

The xx colletion contains:

```
> db.xx.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5158f670c2293fc7aadd811e"),
    "trigger_id" : ObjectId("50c62e97b9fe6a000200000c"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2013-02-11T00:00:00Z")
}
```