# New Date and ISO Date conversion in Mongo shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

I was trying mongoExport with some date condition, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758605/mongoexport-using-gt-and-lt-constraints-on-a-date-range) that date has to be in 
epoch format.

Question is,

I tried below,

```
> new Date(2013,10,16)
ISODate("2013-11-16T00:00:00Z")
```

Assuming that I gave Oct-16-2013, But it returned me '2013-11-16'. Same with epoch format also.

```
> new Date(2013,10,16)*1
1384560000000
> 
> new Date(1384560000000)
ISODate("2013-11-16T00:00:00Z")
```

Can you please help, why its changing the month to 11 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `month` parameter of JavaScript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor is 0-based.  So 0 for January to 11 for December, making it 9 for October instead of 10.

Comment: That sounds bit odd. anyway,Thanks.