# Export Mongo Query

Tags: mongodb, csv, export

I have the following DB:

```
"_id" : ...,
"index" : [
    ...,
    ...,
    ...
],
"value" : {
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    ...
}
```

I want to export all record for which the second element of index is "London" so I used:

mongoexport --db DbReport --collection cityconsumption --query {'index.1':"London"} --csv --out /tmp/me/Query1.csv --username 'DBReport' --password '...' --fields 'index,value'

but I got an error: 
assertion: 10340 Failure parsing JSON string near: index.1:1^

could you please help me.

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: You should warp `--query` parameter with quotes : `--query "{'index.1':'London'}"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongoexport JSON parsing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098191/mongoexport-json-parsing-error)